# ManagementBaseObject and ManagementObject give different DeviceId

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am working on a C# application. Whenever a new USB device is connected to the PC, i have to fire an event and need to get the port on which the device is connected. My code is:

```
private void DeviceInsertedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
        ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
        string PNPDeviceId = instance.Properties["PNPDeviceId"].Value.ToString();
        foreach (var property in instance.Properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " = " + property.Value);
        }

        ManagementObjectCollection ManObjReturn;
        ManagementObjectSearcher ManObjSearch;

        ManObjSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ClassGuid=\"{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\"");

        ManObjReturn = ManObjSearch.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject ManObj in ManObjReturn)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ManObj["DeviceID"]?.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ManObj["PNPDeviceID"]?.ToString());
        }
}
```

Problem is that "ManagementBaseObject" does not provide the information of the port on which the device is conected, to get this information i have to use "ManagementObject", but i can not match the connected device with devices given by "ManagementObjectCollection" because "DeviceID" or "PNPDeviceID" given by ManagementBaseObject and ManagementObject are different. Why the "DeviceID" is different in both cases ? How can i get the port of newly connected USB device ?